# How to start up pc (windows) using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have learned about python script to shutdown the pc like: os.system(shutdown /s /t 0)

But what I was wondering about is to write a script using python which will start up the pc at a specific time after its been shutdown. The os I am using is Windows10.

Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible directly. When your system is shut down no programs can run, including python. However it might be possible to set up Wake On Lan functionality and use python on another computer to send the WOL packet.
Anorher solution would be to go into BIOS (UEFI on newer machines) and schedule wakeup times. No python needed. Or thereay be a way to use python on Win10 to modify UEFI settings in order to set up a wakeup event

Comment: Thanks I will be using the BIOS then

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with BIOS or UEFI settings : https://lifehacker.com/how-can-i-start-and-shut-down-my-computer-automatically-5831504

You can run Python scripts also the boot loader however you can not start up your computer with these scripts : https://lwn.net/Articles/641244/

Comment: Great thanks for the help.. so basically I wanted to start up the pc and then run python script.. I will do the start up with BIOS and then add the python script to start auto with the start up